# How can I change from Meego to Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, meego

I have Meego installed on my newly bought Netbook. I want to change to Ubuntu. I have no files that I want to save or anything and I am completely new to Linux.

Can someone give me a simple step by step guide?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is install Ubuntu over it. Follow the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/145652/54298 and when you get to step 8, you can choose to use all space for Ubuntu.

Comment: @james If it does not work(boot issue), just search with your error message on this site or add a new question. EDIT: If you have a CD already, skip to step 5 in the guide and boot to the CD. If you need help, don't be afraid to comment.

Comment: Remember that if you tell the Ubuntu installer to use all space on the disk for Ubuntu, it will overwrite the existing system and *all files in it*. So if you've put any documents (or other important files) in your Meego system, make sure to offload them elsewhere (as the copies in the Meego system will be destroyed).

Comment: Your guide worked perfectly ObsessiveFOSS ,thank you very much :)

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for adding the warning, I totally forgot to warn the OP.

Comment: @james Remember, you can select this answer as your accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, so future users know this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you install ubuntu over meego and the system will change and the first thing you will have to do is offload all the stuffs you want on a hardrive and there you have it ubuntu installed on your netbook.